# Spring map definition

Tags: java, spring

What's the best way to create a bean for a HashMap`<Class,String`>?

Specifically, do I need to explicitly create a Class bean for the key or is the class name enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean a `Map`, where you don't mind which implementation, rather than specifically a `HashMap`, then use `<util:map>` (see [section A.2.2.5 of the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util)). That will likely create you something like a `LinkedHashMap`, which is probably good enough.

If you really want an actual `HashMap`, then you can specify the `map-class` attribute of `<util:map>` as "`java.util.HashMap"`.

Comment: `util:map` has a `map-class` attribute which does the same. Or do you mean that HashMap can't be created that way (I haven't tried)?

Comment: oh, so it does, I didn't see that. Edited answer.